# Установка и настройка Kerberos

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, kerberos

Ребят такая проблема: есть Ubuntu server 14.04 по вот [этой статье](http://faqpc.ru/nastrojka-dns-servera-ubuntu/) поднял DNS сервер

По [вот этой](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE_ubuntu_server/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8/kerberos) ставлю Kerberos, но на этапе

> kinit steve/admin

вылетает ошибка

> kinit: Cannot find KDC for requested realm while getting initial credentials

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: может быть, имеет смысл указать полное имя? (в терминах статьи: `steve/admin@EXAMPLE.COM`)

Comment: > kinit: Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'EXAMPLE.COM' while getting initial credential

Comment: подставьте то имя, которое использовали при настройке.

Comment: Его и использовал.